# Bolt CMS - how can I remove the class="meta" from the botton

Tags: bolt-cms

I am still setting up on Bolt CMS and still love the design. What I want is clean pages. See this example:

http://bolt_cssc58.bolt.dockerfly.com/page/about

I managed to remove the *Written by Administrator...* and the *Permalink*. But I failed to remove the *« Ille incendat? -* at source. The actual code in this example is:

```
<p class="meta">
<a href="/page/ille-incendat">« Ille incendat?</a>-
</p>
```

Currently suppress it (not in this example of course) at the end of the *body* with:

```
<style>
.meta { 
display: none;  
}
</style>
```

I prefer it not to appear in the first place, but I can't find were the 'meta' comes from. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody has the same issue, I found a solution. In your theme CSS -> /css/app.css simply add:

```
p.meta { 
display: none;  
       }
```